# What is SiteMap(Provider) replacement in .net core+?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, mvcsitemapprovider

Our project site leans heavily on old MvcSiteMapProvider. But it seems that whole sitemap concept ended with .net framework. Is there some new approach or am I missing something?

Comment: I don’t know what the MvcSiteMapProvider did exactly, but if you want a list of all routes you can inject `IEnumerable<EndpointDataSource>` and enumerate over their `Endpoints` properties.

Comment: I didn't find a full replacement, But you can try `SmartBreadcrumbs` in asp.net core. Please refer to this [link](https://dotnetthoughts.net/implementing-breadcrumbs-in-aspnetcore/) to learn more.